# Website to show Amazon's book in search result

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, web-deployment

I want to make a web bookstore with amazon book result, I know how to make website with local database but how can I show amazon books in my web search result, and also show amazon book categories in my website.

Comment: Read the API, use their example code, tweak it.

Comment: Maybe RSS feeds from Amazon will give you the information you need. I don't know if they syndicate the bookstore, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using the amazon API.

[Amazon APi Free Code](http://freecode.com/projects/amazon_webservice_api)

OR

[Amazon Api](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)